# Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectException while using Live SDK in C#/XAML metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, microsoft-metro, live

I am developing a metro app in C#/XAML. I was just coding my self a simple app for uploading and downloading files to my skydrive. I have followed [this](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/skydrive-upload-c-metro/) article, it says to register my app [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=227628). Moreover I searched and found [this][http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/ac748f7f-f077-4bc0-a3f5-1365288f72e7] thread, then I register my app at [here][https://manage.dev.live.com/build], so login is successful but when I try to upload something I am getting "Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectException" at this line.

```
await liveConnectClient.BackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive", file.Name, file, OverwriteOption.Rename);
```

How can I use skydrive for my app for downloading and uploading ? I can't find any good example. I also saw [PhotoSky][http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Live-SDK-Windows-Developer-8ad35141] demo app but it also throws "Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectException".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I didn't associated my app with store. I recommend to read each line of the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631820.aspx#associate_your_app_with_the_store) carefully to new users.

Comment: This link is out of date

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631820.aspx#associate_your_app_with_the_store

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your App capabilities include the internet (Client) capability. If it doesn't then you can allow it through your project properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465399.aspx

**Update:**

I found a workaround to your issue [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/2292cd84-d0cc-4f03-b0f8-a3622db154d0). It is the last post in the thread, see if it works for you. It suggests that you have to use `IStorageFile` for your file, if you're using that then I guess it's an issue with the Live SDK.

Comment: Yes, I have already declared internet (Client) capability, then also not working

Comment: @Xyroid does your app also comply to the file system access restrictions: http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/05/21/winrt-folders-access/

Comment: it has access to all the libraries

Comment: @Xyroid I updated the answer. If this doesn't work with your issue I will remove it.

Comment: still getting "Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectException" and exception message is "A connection to the server could not be established." (P.S. My internet is working perfectly.)